# how to store value from decimal to binary in such a way that it save value in 6 places in c++

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

i have to convert values from 1 to 63(decimal to binary) in such a way that it store in table in 6 place.
for instance, if i enter 2 it convert it into binary: 10 , but i want it to show it in 6-places like 000010. and store it in a table.
i am unable to find a code which convert decimal to binary and show 6 places..what should i do to do this...??

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;  

int main()  
{  
   int a[10], n, i;    
   cout<<"Enter the number to convert: ";    
   cin>>n;    
   for(i=0; n>0; i++)    
   {    
      a[i]=n%2;    
      n= n/2;  
   }    
   cout<<"Binary of the given number= ";    
   for(i=i-1 ;i>=0 ;i--)    
   {    
      cout<<a[i];    
   }    
}
```

i tried this but i convert it into the specified bit like convert 2 in 10, and 3 in 11 same as for others, but i want to convert it into 3=000011.

Comment: You can just modify your existing code a bit. Do you understand what each line of the code is doing?

Comment: Let's say you know you have 2 digits.  And you want to pad with zeros on the left for a total of 6.  So, you have to output 6-2=4 leading zeroes...

Comment: I formatted your code: "indenting" is Good.  A more common approach is to use `>>` and `&` instead of `%` and `/`.  But your algorithm should get the job done.  All you have to do is think a bit further about what you're trying to do before and after your conversion to binary :)

Answer (score 0):

So the one way to solve your problem is: First, initialize the array of 6 elements with zeros...

also you dont have to use an array of 10 as you mentioned clearly that numbers are 1 to 63

```
int a[6], n, i;
```

So you can just add this before your input1

```
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
```

Now the loop you had run doesn't make much sense to me as a programmer, **although I know it is correct**... because the condition is on `n` but increment is on `i`. So I'd change it like this

```
    while (n > 0) {
        a[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
```

And change the `i-1` to 5 (OR MAX_CAP - 1; where MAX_CAP is 6)

```
for(i=5 ;i>=0 ;i--)    
   {    
      cout<<a[i];    
   }
```

But According to me, you should use **vectors** instead of arrays to get rid of that initialization

```
vector<int> a(6,0);
```